# Moving an object inside an array ( Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I have an array of objects something like this

```
arr = [{"class":"section"},{"fieldGroup":[]},{"class":"col","name":"input"},{"class":"col","name":"dropdown"},{"class":"col","name":"date"},{"fieldGroup":[]},{"class":"col","name":"table"}]
```

Now I need to move the objects with `"class":"col"` inside its previous object which contains `"fieldGroup"`

So my desired output should be like this

```
arr = [{"class":"section"},{"fieldGroup":[{"class":"col","name":"input"},{"class":"col","name":"dropdown"},{"class":"col","name":"date"}]},{"fieldGroup":[{"class":"col","name":"table"}]}]
```

I have tried this piece of code

```
arr.forEach((item: any, index: number) => {
    if (item.class === "col") {
            arr[index - 1].fieldGroup.push(item);
            arr.splice(index, 1);
    }else {
        return arr;
    }
})
```

but getting an error saying `cannot read property push of undefined`

any help?

Comment: Use computed property names arr[index - 1][fieldGroup] . Otherwise your are looking for 'fieldGroup' property in your index.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a computed property name in ES5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349480/how-to-use-a-computed-property-name-in-es5)

Comment: Are you 100% certain that objects with `"class":"col"` are _always_ preceded by items with a `fieldGroup` property? The error you're receiving appears to indicate that the object preceding an object with `"class":"col"` doesn't have a `fieldGroup` property.

The sample data you provided appears to work correctly. Do you have a sample where it _doesn't_ work?

Comment: _"I need to move the objects with `"class":"col"`"_ - why are other objects like `{"class":"dropdown"}` also moved when they don't have a `class` of `"col"`?

Comment: sorry my bad @NickParsons I have edited the code

Comment: Hi @garbetjie I have corrected the code sample now which is giving me an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you remove an item from your array using `.splice()` all the items in your `arr` shift down one index. For example, the item that used to be at index `3` will now be at index `2`, the item that used to be at index `4` is will now be at index `3` etc. Your `.forEach()` loop doesn't take this shift into account, and so once you remove the item at index `2` with `.splice()` your `index` changes to `3` for the next iteration, but really, you need to look at index `2` again as your array items have shifted down an index. You can fix this by using a standard `for` loop and decrementing the index counter when you remove an item to look at th inded again:

```js
const arr = [{"class":"section"},{"fieldGroup":[]},{"class":"col","name":"input"},{"class":"col","name":"dropdown"},{"class":"col","name":"date"},{"fieldGroup":[]},{"class":"col","name":"table"}];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const item = arr[i];
  if (item.class === "col") {
    arr[i - 1].fieldGroup.push(item);
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [
  { class: "section" },
  { fieldGroup: [] },
  { class: "col", name: "input" },
  { class: "dropdown" },
  { class: "date" },
  { fieldGroup: [] },
  { class: "col", name: "table" },
];

var res = [];
var currFieldGroup = null;
for (var i in a) {
  if ("fieldGroup" in a[i]) {
    currFieldGroup = a[i];
    res.push(a[i]);
  } else if ("class" in a[i]) {
    if (currFieldGroup) {
      currFieldGroup.fieldGroup.push(a[i]);
    } else {
      res.push(a[i]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

try it ...

```
   var arr = [{"class":"section","name":"input"},{"fieldGroupName":"one","fieldGroup":[]},{"class":"col","name":"input"},{"class":"col","name":"dropdown"},{"class":"section","name":"input"},{"fieldGroupName":"one","fieldGroup":[]},{"class":"col","name":"date"}]
    
    arr.forEach((elm , index) =>{
     if(elm.class == 'col'){ 
         arr[1].fieldGroup.push(elm) 
         arr.splice(index, 1)
    }
})
    
    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
var arr = [{
    "class": "section"
  },
  {
    "fieldGroup": []
  },
  {
    "class": "col",
    "name": "input"
  },
  {
    "class": "dropdown"
  },
  {
    "class": "date"
  },
  {
    "fieldGroup": []
  },
  {
    "class": "col",
    "name": "table"
  }
];

let fieldGroupPosition;
let finalArr = [];
let lastGroupPosition = null;

arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (Array.isArray(item.fieldGroup)) {
    finalArr.push({
      fieldGroup: []
    });
    lastGroupPosition = finalArr.length - 1;
  } else {
    if (lastGroupPosition)
      finalArr[lastGroupPosition].fieldGroup.push(item);
    else
      finalArr.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(finalArr);
```